# How to make custom implemented textView supporting AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uitextview

I create a custom textview (subclass of `UIView`, draw text with TextKit). I want to make the textview work with AutoLayout, i.e. I set the left and right margin, then it calculate the height itself automatically.

I think I should override the `intrinsicContentSize` size, but this function have no input. Height cannot be calculated without the constrained width.

I try to override `sizeThatFits`, which have an constrained size that I want, but it doesn't be called when using AutoLayout.

Comment: You want textview frame be same as its content size?

Answer (score 0):

This intrinsic size must be independent of the content frame, because there’s no way to dynamically communicate a changed width to the layout system based on a changed height, for example.(from documentation)

In your case I'd try to add a height constraint manually inside your custom textView and set its value when you calculate size based on text